# AirDrop iphone to MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, airdrop

At work I airdrop files with coworkers all the time but I often need to move photos from my iphone 5 to my laptop but I can't figure out how.

If I select the images and open the send page which lists options to send my text, email, Facebook, etc.  it lists airdrop above all the other options but it doesn't seem to be clickable.

I have airdrop open on my mac.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote from Apple page http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5887?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

> You can't use AirDrop on iOS to share with OS X users, and OS X users can't use AirDrop to share with iOS devices.

Airdrop between iOS and OS X will be available from iOS8 and Yosemite.

Comment: To further expound on Mateusz's answer, Mac OS X uses Wifi for AirDrop, whilst iOS 7 uses Bluetooth.

Comment: quick update: it does now work properly on from iOS8 to Yosemite, as promised by Apple.